# Compiling with custom vapi leads to error

Tags: development, vala, cmake

Added `CUSTOM_VAPIS` with `vapi/libgtop-2.0.vapi` to `vala_precompile()` in CmakeLists.txt and got this error:
`No rules for target '../src/vapi/libgtop-2.0.vapi' ...`

How to add vapi files properly?

Comment: This is really a CMake question, not Vala, and Vala support isn't built into CMake, so you should link to the file you're using (there are several floating around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CUSTOM_VAPIS` I had to use `--vapidir` option.

```
vala_precompile(VALA_C ${EXEC_NAME}
    ...
PACKAGES
    ...
# CUSTOM_VAPIS
#     ../vapi/libgtop-2.0.vapi
OPTIONS
    --vapidir=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vapi/
    ...
)
```